# Rmarkdown Beamer repeat table header across multiple pages

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer, kable, kableextra

I am building a beamer presentation in rmarkdown and I have a long table that I create using kable and kableExtra, and splitting between two slides. I have been able to split the table fine, but I am having trouble getting the header to repeat. The solutions I have found on the Tex stackexchange pages suggest using different packages, or manually splitting the table in the Tex file. I don't think the additional package suggested, xtab, is compatible with kableExtra. Here is and example of what I am working on.

````
---
title: Title
author: James 
classoption: table
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: ./R presentaion/header.tex

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
long_dt <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
```

#Slide {.allowframebreaks}
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
kable(mtcars, format = "latex", longtable = TRUE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 5, "Group 2" = 6)) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header"), font_size = 6)
```
````

This is what the template file looks like.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xtab}

\def\begincols{\begin{columns}}
\def\begincol{\begin{column}}
\def\endcol{\end{column}}
\def\endcols{\end{columns}}

\def\begincols{\begin{columns}}
\def\begincol{\begin{column}}
\def\endcol{\end{column}}
\def\endcols{\end{columns}}
```

Comment: How about making two tables manually? As suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124939/longtable-in-beamer-environment-lacks-headers-footers

Comment: I could do that, and have before. However, in this case the table is fluid, and will likely change as I continue to work on the project. I was hoping to avoid having to split it manually every time that the table changes.

Comment: As suggested in that post, there is literally nothing we can do, unless you want to make a landscape regular PDF document instead of beamer.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thank you.